# ValueError at /create_post/

Tags: django

When I click the Create New Post button, I get this error.

> The service.views.create_post view did not return an HttpResponse
> object. Instead, it returned None.

views.py

```
    @login_required
    @permission_required("service.add_post")
    def create_post(req):
    form = PostForm()
    if req.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
            if title != "POST":
                messages.error(req, f"Something went wrong")
                return redirect('index')
            id = form.cleaned_data.get("pk")
            messages.success(req, f"Post {title} was created successfully")
            return redirect('index')
        return render(req, "create_post.html", {"form":form})
```

Nothing because I don't understand the error

Comment: The problem is that you are not handling a `GET request` when you first click on the link you make a get request and after submitting you handle the `POST request`

Comment: Try to put this `return render(req, "create_post.html", {"form":form})` outside the `if req.method == "POST":`

Comment: Yes work,thank you